# Limite de Conexão, Query Lenta (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

Realizei um select para me retornar cerca de 70k linhas, tudo estava funcionando perfeitamente até eu adicionar a função "group_concat()", depois de adicionar esta função a query entra em timeout e não consegue me retornar nenhum item.

Existe alguma forma de otimizar este select para que ele fique mais rápido e eu consiga realizar a busca?

```
SELECT 
        UPPER(c.nome)                                                                                                                                   AS Name,
        UPPER(CASE
            WHEN c.sexo = "F" THEN "Sra."
            WHEN c.sexo = "M"  THEN "Sr."
        END)                                                                                                                                            AS Title,
        c.empresa                                                                                                                                       AS Company,
        c.observacoes                                                                                                                                   AS Description,
        CASE
            WHEN c.uf IN ("AC", "AL", "AP", "AM", "BA", "CE", "DF", "ES", "GO", "MA", "MT", "MS", "MG", 
                        "PA", "PB", "PR", "PE", "PI", "RJ", "RN", "RS", "RO", "RR", "SC", "SP", "SE", "TO") THEN "BRASIL"
            ELSE NULL
        END                                                                                                                                             AS Country,
        c.cep                                                                                                                                           AS Zip,
        c.cidade                                                                                                                                        AS City,
        c.uf                                                                                                                                            AS State,
        CONCAT(COALESCE(c.endereco, ' '), " - ", c.complemento_end, " - ", c.bairro)                                                                    AS Adress,
        c.email                                                                                                                                         AS Email,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN sm.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12) THEN CONCAT(sm.url, "/", cm.conta) ELSE CONCAT(sm.url, cm.conta) END SEPARATOR ', ')     AS Website,
        c.telefones                                                                                                                                     AS Phonenumber,
        pt.descricao                                                                                                                                    AS Tags,
        ca.descricao                                                                                                                                    AS Profissão,
        c.rg_nro                                                                                                                                        AS RG,
        c.data_nascimento                                                                                                                               AS 'Data de Nascimento',
        UPPER(c.mothers_name)                                                                                                                           AS 'Nome da Mãe',
        c.sexo                                                                                                                                          AS Sexo,
        ms.descricao                                                                                                                                    AS 'Estado Civil',
        c.escolaridade                                                                                                                                  AS Escolaridade,
        c.renda_estimada                                                                                                                                AS 'Renda Estimada',
        c.risco                                                                                                                                         AS Risco,
        GROUP_CONCAT(it.descricao SEPARATOR ', ')                                                                                                       AS Interesses,
        c.cpf                                                                                                                                           AS CPF

FROM customers_people c
LEFT JOIN customers_social_media cm
ON c.id =  cm.customer_person_id
LEFT JOIN social_media sm
ON cm.social_media_id = sm.id
LEFT JOIN careers ca
ON c.career_id = ca.id
LEFT JOIN marital_status ms
ON c.marital_status_id = ms.id
LEFT JOIN customers_products cp
ON c.id = cp.customer_person_id
LEFT JOIN product pt
ON cp.product_id = pt.id
LEFT JOIN customers_interests ci
ON c.id = ci.customer_id
LEFT JOIN interests it
ON ci.interest_id = it.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: É bem óbvio que tudo acompanha as limitações do hardware, mas uma solução simples é aumentar o *timeout* nessa query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415905/how-to-set-a-maximum-execution-time-for-a-mysql-query

Comment: Já tentou dar um `EXPLAIN` no select pra ver onde estoura?

Comment: Após aumentar o timeout eu consegui, depois de alguns minutos rs, retornar todos os valores que eu precisava. Muito obrigado!!